# Stop a child DIV to inherit style from its Parent Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

Say there is a webpage with its own stylesheet. I have a popup or a modal (appending using Javascript at the end of the page), where I want to have its own style. The content is dynamic so I cannot target each and every element. Is there a way to reset the css inside the child element or restricting the parent stylesheet affecting it?

```css
.headline{ color:blue; text-transform:uppercase;font-size:30px;}
.para{color:green;}
```

```html
<html><body>
  <div class="parent">
    <h2 class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
    <p class="para">
     Phasellus sed molestie quam. Aliquam id sodales est. Fusce non metus lacinia, tempor sapien quis, ultricies nisl.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h2 class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
    <p class="para">
     Phasellus sed molestie quam. Aliquam id sodales est. Fusce non metus lacinia, tempor sapien quis, ultricies nisl.
    </p>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Now The text that comes in the modal is dynamic and I don't want the style for classes *headline* and *para* get inherited. I want modal to take default browser style.Just like the iframe don't get affected by it parent page. Not sure if it is doable.

Comment: Put the child css page to render after the parent css page. This will overwrite the css of the parent page.

Comment: show your code or working sample

Comment: Is your application developed in ReactJS? then you can try CSS modules, that would not override your child page css definitions.

Comment: @MThomas It is not developed in ReactJS

Comment: @TRIKONINDIATRIKONINFOSYSTEMS as I said in my answer, you need to be more specific in your selectors. For the above something like .parent.headline would target only the headline in the parent. but you should be using techniques I've mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

No, the hint is in the name CSS, Cascading Style Sheets. You will need to be more specific with your selectors in the parent. Best practice is to use class selectors and techniques such as BEM, SMACSS, etc to add structure to how elements are targeted:

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/organizing-css-oocss-smacss-and-bem/

Comment: `Sass` does a better job at this too.

Comment: The challenge is I cannot modify the parent page css structure. The modal may dynamically pick any portion on a webpage.

Comment: @TRIKONINDIATRIKONINFOSYSTEMS so the modal markup is loaded in via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I am appending it using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style to unset;
Ex 
margin: unset;
background: unset;
and like wise

Comment: Set the style where? Might as well use best practices instead of hacking the CSS?

Comment: First of all its not about hacking. Its just a way we can unset css without making much effort in javascript. And moreover its a property present in css so why not to use it for ease.